# Reference another route in your routing.yml in Symfony?

Tags: routes, symfony1, propel

Developping a plugin, I have a routing.yml in my plugin dir, specifying a route with sfPropelRoute.

in my *plugins/myPlugin/config/routing.yml* :

```
myplugin_test:
  url:   /myurl/:id
  class:   sfPropelRoute
  options: { model: myClass, type: object, method_for_criteria: selectAvailableObj }
  params: { module: mymodule, action: show }
  requirements:
    sf_method: [GET, POST]
```

it works fine.

But, in my app (*apps/myapp/config/routing.yml*), I want define an absoulute URL, with human meaning
I want to do a routing like this :

```
my_profile:
  url:   /my-super-profile
  class: sfRoute
  params: { route: @myplugin_test, id: 1 }
```

Obviously, my syntax is not the right one !

Comment: Where's the absolute URL you're referring to? Note that both url_for and link_to are able to generate absolute URLs from a routing rule if you pass the "absolute => "true" argument in.

Comment: I want to have the URL :

http://myserver.com/my-super-profile

Comment: I think mere-teresa refers to `/my-super-profile`, which should give the same page as `/myurl/:id` where `id` is 1. So not an absolute but maybe a static url?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the record, I change my method (avoiding the URL rewriting) and I now use a slug.

in my *plugins/myPlugin/config/routing.yml* :

```
myplugin_test:
  url:   /myurl/:slug
  class:   sfPropelRoute
  options: { model: myClass, type: object }
  params: { module: mymodule, action: show}
  requirements:
    sf_method: [GET, POST]
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a `route` parameter in sfRoute.

You might want instead to write a RewriteRule for that particular URL:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/my-super-profile$ /myurl/1 [L,QSA]
```